# Why these linked files are missing?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm trying to upload a revit file with linked documents.

All the documents are in the same folder, and same bucket. ALL THE TIMES.

1 - You need to upload your files to the bucket. DONE!

2 - You need to Create References for the Composite Source File using this endpoint:
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-references-POST/

Ok, let's see if I can create a reference to a invalid file...
[image: Creating invalid reference]

OK Forge recognized that one of my reference files did not exist!
Nice.

Now let's send valid files:

[image: Valid files equals valid response]

Ok, it should be fine.

Now let's go to the final step... Let's start the job to translate the file to SVF!

[image: Missing links]

Forge says that the linked files are missing, why?

Here are the requests...

References:

```
{
    "urn": "urn:adsk.objects:os.object:federado/PL076-ARQ-EMB.rvt",
    "filename":"PL076-ARQ-EMB.rvt",
    "references": [
        {"urn":"urn:adsk.objects:os.object:federado/PL076-HID-EMB.rvt", "metadata": {"Teste":"Gabriel"}},
        {"urn":"urn:adsk.objects:os.object:federado/PL076-INC-EMB.rvt", "metadata": {"Teste":"Gabriel"}},
        {"urn":"urn:adsk.objects:os.object:federado/PL076-ACO-EMB.rvt", "metadata": {"Teste":"Gabriel"}},
        {"urn":"urn:adsk.objects:os.object:federado/PL076-ARQ-TOR01-FAC.rvt", "metadata": {"Teste":"Gabriel"}},
        {"urn":"urn:adsk.objects:os.object:federado/PL076-ARQ-TOR01-OPC01.rvt", "metadata": {"Teste":"Gabriel"}},
        {"urn":"urn:adsk.objects:os.object:federado/PL076-ELE-EMB.rvt", "metadata": {"Teste":"Gabriel"}},
        {"urn":"urn:adsk.objects:os.object:federado/PL076-ENG-EMB.rvt", "metadata": {"Teste":"Gabriel"}},
        {"urn":"urn:adsk.objects:os.object:federado/PL076-EST-CORDOALHAS.rvt",  "metadata": {"Teste":"Gabriel"}},
        {"urn":"urn:adsk.objects:os.object:federado/PL076-EST-EMB.rvt","metadata": {"Teste":"Gabriel"}}
    ]

}
```

JOB

```
{
   "input": {
     "urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6ZmVkZXJhZG8vUEwwNzYtQVJRLUVNQi5ydnQ",
     "checkReferences": true
    },
   "output": {
     "formats": [
        {
          "type": "svf",
          "views": [
            "2d",
            "3d"
          ]
        }
     ]
   }
}
```

As you can see, the first request uses URN's without encoding to Base64, and the second one uses the encoding on the URN parameter. That's because their documentation says it should be like this.

So, any guesses why the links are missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the [reference API of the Model Derivate](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-references-POST/) doesn't support Revit files currently as I know. Please upload a ZIP that contains the host RVT and its links to Forge OSS and trigger a translation job with this request body:

```
{
   "input": {
     "urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6ZmVkZXJhZG8vUEwwNzYtQVJRLUVNQi56aXA",
     "compressedUrn": true,
     "rootFilename": "PL076-ARQ-EMB.rvt"
   },
   "output": {
     "formats": [
       {
         "type": "svf",
         "views": [
           "2d",
           "3d"
         ]
       }
     ]
   }
 }
```

If those models are uploaded onto your own managed Forge OSS bucket and they are not deleted yet, then you have to download all files included host and links and pack them to a zip and reupload again for translation.

Commonly, Forge OSS will delete all uploaded files automatically after 24hours with the transient bucket retention policy (the default policy in our codes samples and tutorials, you can change it as you want, see [OSS Retention Policy page](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/developers_guide/retention-policy/) for details)

However, there is another way to see all your models in the same viewer scene - use Forge Viewer to load individual SVF model translated from your RVTs into the same scene. It’s well-known as the aggregate/multiple model scenario of the viewer. You can choose either way to achieve what you want.

BTW,

In multiple model scenario, you can obtain loaded models via accessing `viewer.impl.modelQueue().getModels()` and get selection set via `viewer.getAggregateSelection()`.

If your models are translated from a zip, you can determine if it’s from linked files via the external id of the element you selected. The external id for the Revit model is the `Element.UniqueId` in Revit API. Each element in Revit has a unique GUID called `UniqueId` and be assigned when the element was placed to the Revit view.

In the Forge Viewer, you can obtain the item's external id via calling `viewer.getProperties( dbId )`. For item from links, the external will look like
`65e0379f-2c38-40b3-b403-2979327abc7a-00080a4e/22858843-3747-4f42-8654-519948201028-000eaf08`. There would be a `/` slash inside.

Hope it helps. Cheers!

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply Eason!
I´ve tried to do as you're saying, but I was unable to find the linked files in the metadata endpoint.

After you send the zip file and translate it, where can you get the linked files?
I tried "GET :urn/manifest" and  "GET :urn/metadata" but no sign of the linked files.

Comment: I don't need the files, I just need to know what are the linked files and what are the objects that comes from the linked file, so I can do things like ghosting all objects from a specific file. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi, Gabrie, linked files are individual RVT file in Revit. Forge server won't have them if you didn't upload them to Forge OSS before. Please contact the owner of those linked files from your end yourself. Afterward, pack them with the host RVT as a zip file. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Eason, but as I said before, I have already uploaded ALL THE FILES to forge. So with all the files in Forge, I need to retrieve which are the linked files and what objects comes from each file. Then I can work. If I have a linked model, this linked model is made of more than one file. Each file has it's objects. So I need to be able to filter the objects by file, to do that I need to know which are the linked files.

Comment: It depends on what bucket policy you choose, commonly it’s deleted after 24hours with the transient policy. If they are not deleted automatically and you want like to link them together, you have to download all files included host and links, then pack them to a zip and trip load again for translation. The reference API didn’t support Revit files currently as I mentioned above.

Comment: Another way to use Forge Viewer to load individual SVF model translated from your RVTs in the same viewer scene. It’s well-known as the aggregate/multiple models scenario of the viewer. You can choose either way to achieve what you want.

Comment: In multiple model scenario, you can obtain models via accessing viewer.impl.modelQueue().getModels()

Comment: If your models are translated from a zip, you can determine if it’s from linked files via the external id of the element you selected. There would be a / slash inside the external id.

Comment: Wow very nice, I was wondering what does the and external ID guid/guid was for.  One last thing, would you kindly edit your answer with the information in your last comment? So that I can mark this as the accepted answer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just catch your message due to time diff. I have added my comments above to the answer section. Cheers!